# Empty pipe using GIOChannel

Tags: c, gtk, fork, pipe

I'm new to GTK and I'm working on a GUI for a program that connects to a server. I used a `fork` to separate the logic (command line client) from the GUI. Logic and GUI use pipes to communicate.

Sometimes the GUI reads several empty messages from the pipe and I don't understand why.

I tried to make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), but I can't replicate the problem in my simplified example. Anyway, this is roughly how the program works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int gui_pipe[2], logic_pipe[2];

gboolean deliver_signal(GIOChannel *source, GIOCondition cond, gpointer d) {
    gchar readbuffer[100];
    char ack[] = "ack";
    read(gui_pipe[0], readbuffer, 100);
    g_print("I received: %s\n",readbuffer);
    write(logic_pipe[1], ack, strlen(ack));
    return(TRUE);
}

main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GtkBuilder *builder;
    GtkWidget *window;
    GIOChannel *g_signal_in;
    if(pipe(gui_pipe)==-1) {
        perror("pipe call");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(pipe(logic_pipe)==-1) {
        perror("pipe call");
        exit(1);
    }
    switch(fork()) {
        case -1:
            perror("fork call");
            exit(2);
        case 0: /* Child (GUI) */
            close(gui_pipe[1]);
            close(logic_pipe[0]);
            gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
            builder = gtk_builder_new();
            gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder, "mygui.glade", NULL);
            window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window1"));
            g_signal_in = g_io_channel_unix_new(gui_pipe[0]);
            g_io_add_watch(g_signal_in, G_IO_IN, deliver_signal, NULL);
            gtk_widget_show(window);  
            gtk_main();
        default: /* Parent (Logic) */
            close(gui_pipe[0]);
            close(logic_pipe[1]);
            char msg[] = "Hello!";
            char readbuffer[100];
            int i;
            for(i=0;i<5;i++) {
                printf("LOGIC: I'm sending %s\n",msg);
                write(gui_pipe[1], msg, strlen(msg));
                read(logic_pipe[0], readbuffer, 100);
                printf("LOGIC: I received: %s\n", readbuffer);
            }
            exit(0);
    }

}
```

This version doesn't read empty pipes but the original program does it (always 7 times!).
The only solution that I've found is this:

```
do {
    read(gui_pipe[0], readbuffer, 100);
} while(strcmp("",readbuffer)==0);
```

I also tried to use `g_io_channel_read_chars()` instead of `read()` but it doesn't work too.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer when the code you're showing is also known to work.

You should at least check the `condition` argument in your callback, perhaps something is causing [non-read conditions](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-IO-Channels.html#GIOCondition) to be reported in the problematic program?

Comment: I see always `G_IO_IN` condition and the status returned by `g_io_channel_read_chars()` is always `G_IO_STATUS_NORMAL`

Comment: Hi, I solved (without understanding why). In a part of the code I used `sizeof()` instead of `strlen()`. Using `strlen()` everywhere it works. I'm still unable to replicate the problem...
Anyway, thank you for the answer!